# how to call controller method from view (.tpl) file in prestashop

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I have created one back office module.I want to call my module controller method from view (.tpl) file. plz provide some instruction.

Thanx In Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a tab for you controller

```
 private function _createTab($class_name, $nom_tab,$parent)
{
/* define data array for the tab  */
$data = array(
              'id_tab' => '', 
              'id_parent' => Tab::getIdFromClassName($parent), 
              'class_name' => $class_name, 
              'module' => 'moduleName', 
              'position' => 1, 'active' => 1 
             );

/* Insert the data to the tab table*/
$res = Db::getInstance()->insert('tab', $data);
if(!$res) return false;
//Get last insert id from db which will be the new tab id
$id_tab = Db::getInstance()->Insert_ID();

//Define tab multi language data
$data_lang = array(
                 'id_tab' => $id_tab, 
                 'id_lang' => Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT'),
                 'name' => $nom_tab
                 );

 // Now insert the tab lang data
$res &= Db::getInstance()->insert('tab_lang', $data_lang);
 if(!$res) return false;

return true;

}
```

Call it in your install method like this

```
$this->_createTab('AdminModuleController', 'tab name','AdminDashboard');
```

And in your view, for example in your form action, you can call it

```
<form action="index.php?controller=AdminModuleController">
```

Comment: I want post data on it.. so it's necessary to create tab ?

Comment: To call it, you should add a tab, you can set it disabled.

Comment: You should add your code in admin controller  initContent method

Comment: Thank You tarek fellah for advice me.